# Ipad like CSS Form

Tags: css

I've been searching a css form design that looks like below. Could any one tell me whether anyone has already created this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

http://www.k33g.org/?q=node/55

Comment: Yep, but the download link is broken :-(